# Русские буквы в корзине Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Здравствуйте, есть установленная корзина в Codeigniter.
Все работает, кроме тех товаров в которых имена написаны русскими буквами
по гуглил, нашел [решение](http://wwarlock.blogspot.com/2010/03/codeigniter.html)
сделал все так же, и теперь получаю ошибку как заношу товар

```
Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 17

Filename: libraries/Cart.php

Line Number: 186
```

что это может быть? кодировка стоит utf-8

**186 строка**

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/iu", $items['name']))
```

Comment: Для полноты картины, а что содержится в `$this->product_name_rules`

Comment: var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я';

Comment: сочетание `:-_` это не ошибка ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам файл `libraries/Cart.php` в utf-8 (без BOM) ?

Comment: Прошу прощение) сам Файл был ANSI. все работает